# rowMeans function returns value "0" for cases with NAs

Tags: r

I am preparing my data for analysis and would like to calculate scales from several items. I usually do this using either the rowMeans or rowSums function. However, for one of my scales, the function returns a value of 0 for those participants who have all NAs on those items (when the scale score should also be NA, not 0). Can someone help me understand what the problem might be?

Here's my code for this particular line:

```
data$scale <- with(data, rowMeans(cbind(item1, item2), na.rm=TRUE))
```

Thanks very much for your help.
Charlotte

Comment: Can you provide a [reprex](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates this behavior?

Comment: It depends if you use `rowSums` or `rowMeans`. The first will return 0 and the latter will return NaN

Comment: if you do rowMeans(cbind(c(NA,NA),c(NA,NA)),na.rm=TRUE), it gives NA NA, if you do rowSums(cbind(c(NA,NA),c(NA,NA)),na.rm=TRUE) it gives 0 0 , so which one might it be?

Comment: Thanks very much for your answers. Since `rowSums`returns 0, how can I best address this in my code? If that question is not straightforward to answer, I'll post an attempt at a reproducible example later.

Comment: There may be a cleaner way to do this, but since `rowMeans` is calculated using the sum of the non-missing values divided by the number of non-missing values, you can convert the mean to a sum by multiplying by the number of non-missing elements in the row.  `rowMeans(cbind(c(1,NA),c(2,NA)),na.rm=TRUE)` returns 1.5 and NaN, but if you multiply that by `rowSums(!is.na(cbind(c(1,NA),c(2,NA))),na.rm=TRUE)`, you'll get 3 and NaN.